# Wants to make KeyBoard Action with an Option to Stop

Tags: c#

I want to create a program that makes keyboard event for every 10 seconds.

but once my code starts to perform,
it can't stop until it's finished.

Is there any way to stop to close the program??

Can I make it detect my keyboard action by two seconds, like detect hitting ESC to stop the program?

My code is at below.

```
private void StartAction()
{
    int minutes = 2;
    Process pr = Process.Start("notepad.exe");

    for (int a = 0; a < minutes; a++)
    {
        for (int b = 0; b < 6; b++)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(2000);
            Thread.Sleep(2000);
            Thread.Sleep(2000);
            Thread.Sleep(2000);
            Thread.Sleep(2000);
            SendKeys.Send("KeyBoard Action");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes its easier to just use a timer.

```
using System.Threading;

...

private static Timer _myTimer;

private static volatile bool _isCancled;

private static void Main(string[] args)
{
   _myTimer = new Timer(Callback, null, 2000, 2000);

   Console.ReadLine();
}

private static void Callback(object state)
{
   if (_isCancled)
   {
      _myTimer.Change(0, 0);
      return;
   }

   try
   {
      //SendKeys.Send("KeyBoard Action");
      Console.WriteLine("blah");
   }
   catch (Exception ex)
   {
      //Handle Exception
   }
}
```

or another way

```
Task.Run(async () =>
   {
      while (!_isCancled)
      {
         await Task.Delay(2000);
         //SendKeys.Send("KeyBoard Action");
         Console.WriteLine("blah");    
      }
   });
```

Just for completeness, the optimal way to cancel a task is using a *Cancellation Token*. You can read more about them here

[CancellationToken Structure](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.cancellationtoken(v=vs.110).aspx)

> Propagates notification that operations should be canceled.

Answer (score 0):

Add a condition inside the for loop, so that it will exit when requested.

```
if (condition)
{
    break;
}
```

Edit: Because of the `Thread.Sleep` everywhere, the program won't actually be able to have a conditional change, example, if you're condition was when the user pressed f1, the condition would never become true because the `Thread.Sleep` would block the thread, therefore the users input would never be recognized. Try not to use so many `Thread.Sleep`, if any at all. If it is absolutely necessary, I advise you to use an `async` method, or use `Timers`.